# Network Register a Headless Device

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy

I have a Raspberry Pi (but also applies to any headless machine). I SSH into the machine, but I can't go anywhere else unless I share my internet with it via OS X.

To use the internet, each device has to enter a username/password through a webform.

What are the recommended ways to performing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be surprised this question has not been asked before...

In any case: the basic command is:

```
   curl --user name:password http://IP_address_of_thecaptivePortal -v
```

(the *-v* option, for *verbose*, is useful since you are doing this for the first time). However, it may prove useful to allow cookies,

```
   curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt --data "Username=xx&Password=xx&Login=Login" http://IP_address_o_the_captive_portal
```

Keeping cookies will allow you to appear as registered already at your next request.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to curl, you could use a terminal-based web browser. There are a few of them, but I would suggest [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29).

The main issue with this is that you'll have to find a way to install it. You could find a temporary Internet connection somewhere else to do this.

To install it you can run something similar to `sudo apt-get install lynx`.

To run Lynx you can run `lynx -accept_all_cookies http://(webform address)`. You can then use the up and down arrows to highlight links on the page. The right arrow will follow the link that is highlighted and the left arrow goes to the previous page. `Control/Command + C` exits the browser.